# Scope changes do not propogate to the parent scope (angular, bootstrap datetime picker)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scope, datetimepicker, angular-ngmodel

I have got a [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) that I am using with angular js.. first I'll show some code.

the html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class= "row">
        <div class= "col-sm-6">
            <div class= "form-group">
                <div class= "input-group date" id= "datetimepicker1">
                    <input ng-model= "startDate" type= "text" class= "form-control" />
                    <span class= "inpu-group-addon">
                        <span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input type= "button" value= "Check Value" ng-click= "check()"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript

```
app.controller('DateTimePicker', [
    '$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.check = function() {
            alert($scope.startDate);
        }

        function init() {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            $('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change', function() {
                $scope.startDate = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
            });
        }

        init();

    }
]);
```

This is the gist of my setup. Now, when I click the "Check Value" button, I get undefined. This happens ever after I open the popup menu and select a date/time.

I thought this was because the "check" function is defined as a part of the Controller level scope, and anything that was selected (as "startDate") in the datetimepicker was part of a different child scope.

A small test seems to have confirmed this.

```
$scope.startDate = "2016-07-05";

$scope.check = function() {
    alert($scope.startDate);       // this gets called with the value above
}
```

The hardcoded value gets alerted, but it is never updated to the value I select inside the datepicker... EVEN with the listener I assigned to it to more or less set it manually.

Is there a way I can get the scopes to stop clashing in this way?

Comment: I'd recommend switching datetime plugins to a pure angular solution like the one in ui-bootstrap

Comment: @jbrown is right, jQuery plugins and AngularJS doesn't work seamlessly. You can't use jQuery plugin and expect data will propagate to `ngModel`  just like that.

Comment: I need something with a time picker as well. Was really hoping that I could just use the library that existed, rather than trying to hack together several libraries.

Comment: Take a look at this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap - you can find datpicker/timepicker- everything already prepared to be used with AngularJS

Comment: I'll try a brief example with that

Answer (score 0):

Try to add: $scope.digest() after changing $scope.startDate.

Comment: Adding $scope.$digest looks like it updated $scope.startDate, but to the empty string... it isn't undefined anymore, but it isn't the date string either.

Comment: Sorry, it did this before adding the $scope.digest as well.

Comment: can you post a plunker so I can debug?